# Can I have multiple images marked up in a schema.org ImageObject?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

In an HTML5 `figure` element, you can have multiple images inside. However, if you have the `figure` marked up as an `ImageObject`, can you mark up all the images inside of the figure with `itemprop="contentUrl"` or should only the first be marked up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you’d use one [`ImageObject`](http://schema.org/ImageObject) with multiple [`contentUrl`](http://schema.org/contentUrl) properties, it would mean that you have *one* image with several URLs.

If you have several images, use an own `ImageObject` item for each.

Comment: I'm asking if the figure element itself is marked up as the ImageObject and I have multiple images within. Should I just mark the first image with itemprop="contentUrl"?

Comment: @A.J.Maciejewski: One `ImageObject` item represents exactly one image; it doesn’t matter how many `img` elements the `figure` element contains or how often you use the `contentUrl` property. If you want to represent multiple images with Schema.org, you have to add multiple `ImageObject` items.

Comment: @A.J.Maciejewski: If you are restricted somehow, so that you can’t change the Microdata and you *have* to keep the `itemscope` on the `figure` and can’t add child elements with `itemscope`, then you should only add the `contentUrl` property for *one* image. The other images don’t get represented with Schema.org in that case.

Comment: Thanks! Now it makes a lot more sense.